# Show individual dates unless they're consecutive dates

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I'm working on an application that shows event listings. Originally, the application was using Drupal and was showing events as 'ranges'. So if there is an event on 3/4, 3/6, 3/8 it would display the dates as 3/4 - 3/8.

I recently ported this application to a custom solution since the events have become more advanced. The client just requested that this behavior is confusing. He would like it to say 3/4, 3/6, 3/8 BUT we need handling for consecutive dates as well.

So if we have events 3/4, 3/6, 3/8 AND 3/10, 3/11, 3/12 - we would need to see the following
3/4, 3/6, 3/8, 3/10-3/12

Currently the event listings has a master events table

```
EventID (int)
Event (varchar)
Active (tinyint)
```

And a Event Date table

```
EventDateID(int)
EventDate
EventTime
EventID
```

Here is my SQL for this

```
SELECT *, MIN(tblEventDates.EventDate) AS minDate
FROM tblEvents INNER JOIN tblEventDates
ON tblEvents.EventID = tblEventDates.EventID
WHERE tblEvents.Active = 1
AND tblEventDates.EventDate >= CURDATE()
GROUP BY tblEvents.EventID
ORDER By minDate, EventTime
```

I am INNER JOINing these two tables to produce the listings of events. During that output loop I query again grabbing the individual EventDates and produce the range

```
SELECT MAX(EventDate) AS maxDate, MIN(EventDate) AS minDate
FROM tblEventDates
WHERE EventID = '$EventID'
```

I'm just not sure what the best way is to determine if this part of a range or isolated date to display.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is something better done in client-side code. SQL is more designed for data retrieval, not data formatting.

Comment: I think the best solution will be to handle this via PHP in the loop (see second query)

Comment: this could be done easily with PHP using `DateTime` and `DateInterval`....you will of course have to construct your dates differently depending how they are stored in your db. I believe the default DATETIME is a "YYYY-MM-DD" string, a simple `explode` should do the trick

Comment: Solved it from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8461543/check-for-consecutive-dates-within-a-set-and-return-as-range?lq=1

Comment: Solved using this code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8461543/check-for-consecutive-dates-within-a-set-and-return-as-range?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand why you are not just getting the range in your original query:

```
SELECT *, MIN(tblEventDates.EventDate) AS minDate, MAX(tblEventDates.EventDate) AS maxDate
FROM tblEvents INNER JOI
     tblEventDates
     ON tblEvents.EventID = tblEventDates.EventID
WHERE tblEvents.Active = 1 AND
      tblEventDates.EventDate >= CURDATE()
GROUP BY tblEvents.EventID
ORDER By minDate, EventTime;
```

If you do this, then you don't need additional queries to get the `maxDate`.

Comment: I have mixed dates AND ranges. This is the output I'm trying to achieve.. "So if we have events 3/4, 3/6, 3/8 AND 3/10, 3/11, 3/12 - we would need to see the following 3/4, 3/6, 3/8, 3/10-3/12"

Comment: @hanji . . . Can you edit your question, providing sample data and desired results?

Comment: So if we have events 3/4, 3/6, 3/8 AND 3/10, 3/11, 3/12 - we would need to see the following 3/4, 3/6, 3/8, 3/10-3/12 I need a mix of date items and ranges. I think PHP is the way to go for this. I just through in MySQL.. but the solution will be a function that gets fed an array of dates.

Comment: @hanji . . . That is not what the code in the question does.

Comment: Ugh.. yep. Anyways.. I found the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8461543/check-for-consecutive-dates-within-a-set-and-return-as-range?lq=1