# Some help "syncing" two loops in PHP

Tags: php, loops

I've implemented following solution by @Darragh to find consecutive dates and transforming them into date ranges:

> [Check for consecutive dates within a set and return as range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8461543/check-for-consecutive-dates-within-a-set-and-return-as-range)

Now, I'm trying to print some additional information to the output of this loop.
This is the erroneous script I've created, based on @Darragh 's answer:

```
<?php
$output = '';
$dates = array();
$query = 'SELECT name, company, date FROM project GROUP BY date ORDER BY date';
$sth   = $dbh->prepare($query);
$sth->execute();
if($sth->rowCount() > 0) {
    $output .= '<ul>';
    while($row = $sth->fetch()) {
        array_push($dates,new DateTime($row['date']));
        $name = $row['name'];
        $company = $row['company'];
    }
    $lastDate = null;
    $ranges = array();
    $currentRange = array();
    foreach ($dates as $date) {
        if (null === $lastDate) {
            $currentRange[] = $date;
        } else {
            $interval = $date->diff($lastDate);
            if ($interval->days === 1) {
                $currentRange[] = $date;
            } else {
                $ranges[] = $currentRange;
                $currentRange = array($date);
            }
        }
        $lastDate = $date;
    }
    $ranges[] = $currentRange;
    foreach ($ranges as $range) {
        $saverange = array();
        foreach($range as $entry) {
            array_push($saverange,$entry->format('Y-m-d'));
        }
        $startDate = array_shift($range);
        $str = sprintf('%s', $startDate->format('d/m/Y'));
        if (count($range)) {
            $endDate = array_pop($range);
            $str .= sprintf(' tot %s', $endDate->format('d/m/Y'));
        }
        $output .= '<li>'.$name.', '.$company.' - '.$str.'</li>';
    }
    $output .= '</ul>';

    // Show me what you got
    echo $output;
}
?>
```

Obviously, the `while` loop that loops over the DB output is out of sync with the `foreach` loop that outputs the dateranges.

The raw DB output is as follows:

```
+------------------+-------------+------------+
|       name       |   company   |    date    |
+------------------+-------------+------------+
| EBU              | Belgacom sa | 2014-09-12 |
| Mosquito Replica | Mosquito nv | 2014-09-17 |
| Mosquito Replica | Mosquito nv | 2014-09-19 |
| Mosquito Replica | Mosquito nv | 2014-09-20 |
+------------------+-------------+------------+
```

What my script outputs is as follows:

```
<ul>
  <li>Mosquito Replica, Mosquito nv - 12/09/2014</li>
  <li>Mosquito Replica, Mosquito nv - 17/09/2014</li>
  <li>Mosquito Replica, Mosquito nv - 19/09/2014 tot 20/09/2014</li>
</ul>
```

What I need it to output is as follows:

```
<ul>
  <li>EBU, Belgacom sa - 12/09/2014</li>
  <li>Mosquito Replica, Mosquito nv - 17/09/2014</li>
  <li>Mosquito Replica, Mosquito nv - 19/09/2014 tot 20/09/2014</li>
</ul>
```

This might be obvious to you guys, but I cannot for the life of me figure it out.
Who will show me the way? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the interval is one day, but the name/company is different, should this result in a separate range? if not, which name/company should be displayed?

Comment: Hi, no, only non-consecutive dates should present a new line. Good point!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your script is not printing `EBU, Belgacum sa` lies in this part:

```
while($row = $sth->fetch()) {
    array_push($dates,new DateTime($row['date']));
    $name = $row['name'];
    $company = $row['company'];
}
```

While the date values are pushed to an array, `$name` and `$company` are overwritten by each new line.

Further, I think your script overcomplicates the issue. How about this?

```
    $output = '';
    $list = array();
    $lastitem = $lastdate = null;
    $query = 'SELECT name, company, date FROM project GROUP BY date ORDER BY date, name, company';
    $sth   = $dbh->prepare($query);
    $sth->execute();
    if($sth->rowCount() > 0) {
            $i = 0;
        while($row = $sth->fetch()) {
                $date = new DateTime($row['date']);
                $item = array(
                    'date' => array(),
                    'name' => $row['name'],
                    'company' => $row['company'],
                );
                if ($item === $lastitem && $date->diff($lastdate)->days === 1) {
                    $list[$i-1]['date']['end'] = $date;
                }
                else {
                    $list[$i] = $item;
                    $list[$i]['date']['start'] = $date;


                    $lastitem = $item;
                    $lastdate = $date;
                    $i++;
                }
        }
    }
    if (count($list)) {
            $output .= '<ul>';
    }
    foreach ($list AS $item) {
            $output .= '<li>' . $item['name'] . ', ' . $item['company'] . ' - ' . $item['date']['start']->format('d/m/Y');
            $output .= isset($item['date']['end']) ? ' tot ' . $item['date']['end']->format('d/m/Y') : '';
            $output .= '</li>';
    }
    if (count($list)) {
            $output .= '</ul>';
    }
```

Comment: do you have any idea why this functionality breaks if I change my query to select the ID of the table? The ranges don't get recognized anymore in that case...

Comment: You should probably open a new question for that including the updated db schema (there's no ID in this question).

Comment: please note that I've posted a follow up question regarding this subject here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27298069/consecutive-dateranges-in-php

Answer (score 1):

The client code should look like this:

```
<?php

$output = '';
$query = 'SELECT name, company, date FROM project GROUP BY date ORDER BY date';
$sth = $dbh->prepare($query);
$sth->execute();
if ($sth->rowCount() > 0) {
    $rows = array();
    $output .= '<ul>';

    //object responsible for holidng all the ranges 
    //and returning the reference to them based on date
    $dateRange = new TimeRange();

    while ($row = $sth->fetch()) {
        //getting the period id for this row's time
        $row['range_id'] = $dateRange->getRangeId(new DateTime($row['date']));
        //indexing by name, company and range id
        $rows[$row['name'] . $row['company'] . $row['range_id']] = $row;
    }

    //each row has it's range id, now we just loop through them and render
    //Time Period object is rendering itself
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $output .= '<li>' . $row['name'] . ', ' . $row['company']
                . ' - ' . $dateRange->render($row['range_id']) . '</li>';
    }

    $output .= '</ul>';

// Show me what you got
    echo $output;
}
```

And classes to make the client code run (one possible implementation):

```
class TimeRange {

    /**
     * @var TimePeriod[]
     */
    private $periods = array();

    /**
     * @var TimePeriod
     */
    private $currentPeriod;

    private function newPeriod(DateTime $time) {
        $this->currentPeriod = new TimePeriod($time);
        $this->periods[] = $this->currentPeriod;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the period id for the given date
     * @param DateTime $time
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRangeId(DateTime $time) {
        if ($this->currentPeriod === null) {
            $this->newPeriod($time);
        }

        if (!$this->currentPeriod->setNewEndTime($time)) {
            $this->newPeriod($time);
        }

        //returning period id
        end($this->periods);
        return key($this->periods);
    }

    /**
     * Renders the time period based on provided id
     * @param string $periodId
     * @return string
     */
    public function render($periodId) {
        return $this->periods[$periodId]->render();
    }

}

class TimePeriod {

    /**
     * @var DateTime
     */
    private $startTime;

    /**
     * @var DateTime
     */
    private $endTime;

    public function __construct(DateTime $startTime) {
        $this->startTime = $startTime;
    }

    /**
     * Attepmts to set the end time for the period
     * if the given time is more than 1 day apart from the current end time
     * the period is ended
     * @param DateTime $time
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function setNewEndTime(DateTime $time) {
        $compareTime = $this->endTime !== null ? $this->endTime : $this->startTime;
        $interval = $compareTime->diff($time);
        $dateSet = $interval->days <= 1;

        if ($dateSet) {
            $this->endTime = $time;
        } else {
            $this->endTime = $this->startTime;
        }

        return $dateSet;
    }

    /**
     * Renders the time period
     * if the end time is less than a day apart only start time is rendered
     * @return string
     */
    public function render() {
        $render = $this->startTime->format('d/m/Y');

        if ($this->startTime->diff($this->endTime, true)->days >= 1) {
            $render .= ' tot ' . $this->endTime->format('d/m/Y');
        }

        return $render;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, Nicola, for your extensive answer. I went with @Paul 's answer, because I'm not so familiar with OO programming, and most of my code is structured... I'm sure this would make a fine solution though!