# Consecutive dateranges in PHP

Tags: php, loops, datetime

This is a follow-up question for my earlier question here:
[Some help "syncing" two loops in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26893988/some-help-syncing-two-loops-in-php)

I want to take a list of dates and show them as ranges if their date is the same or max 1 day apart.

This is the output of my database:

```
+-----+------------+
| uid |    date    |
+-----+------------+
|  39 | 2014-09-17 |
|  46 | 2014-09-18 |
|  40 | 2014-09-19 |
|  48 | 2014-09-19 |
|  45 | 2014-09-20 |
|  47 | 2014-12-05 |
+-----+------------+
```

This is the HTML I want to generate:

> Contract from 17/09/2014 to 20/09/2014
>
> UIDS: 39-46-40-48-45
>
> ---
>
> Contract from 05/12/2014
>
> UIDS: 47
>
> ---

This is my sourcecode

```
<?php
$output = '';
$list = array();
$lastitem = $lastdate = null;
$query = 'SELECT * FROM project_dates';
$sth  = $dbh->prepare($query);
$sth->execute();
if($sth->rowCount() > 0) {
    $i = 0;
    while($row = $sth->fetch()) {
        // CURRENT DATE
        $date = new DateTime($row['date']);

        // STORAGE
        $item = array(
            'date' => array(),
            'var' => $row['uid'], // A '-' delimited variable of all the uids in the range (40-41-...)
            'uids' => array() // An array of all the uids in the range
        );

        // IF THE DATE DIFF IS LESS THAN OR EQUAL TO ONE DAY
        if ($item['date'] === $lastitem['date'] && $date->diff($lastdate)->days <= 1) {
            // Problem here: looking for last date in set!
            $list[$i-1]['date']['end'] = $date;
            //Add current uid to the '-' delimited variable of uids of this range
            $list[$i-1]['uid'] = $list[$i-1]['uid'].'-'.$item['uid'];
            // Add current uid to the array of uids of this range               
            array_push($list[$i-1]['uids'],$item['uid']);
        } else {
            // Next range
            $list[$i] = $item;
            $list[$i]['date']['start'] = $date;
            $lastitem = $item;
            $lastdate = $date;
            array_push($list[$i]['uids'],$item['uid']);
            $i++;
        }
    }
}
if(count($list)){
    // Show text with first date and last date of the range
    $output .= 'Contract from '.$item['date']['start']->format('d/m/Y');
    $output .= isset($item['date']['end']) ? ' to ' . $item['date']['end']->format('d/m/Y') : '';
    $output .= '<br />Uids: '.$item['var'];
}
foreach ($list AS $item) {
    // Loop over the dates in this range
    $output .= $item['date'].'<br />';
}
if(count($list)) {
    // Line under this range 
    $output .= '<hr />';
}

echo $output;
?>
```

For some reason, my code returns 4 ranges instead of 2. I've been trying to figure out for hours why. Can someone help me? This is the faulty HTML:

> Contract from 17/09/2014 to 18/09/2014
>
> UIDS: 39-46
>
> ---
>
> Contract from 19/09/2014
>
> UIDS: 40
>
> ---
>
> Contract from 19/09/2014 tot 20/09/2014
>
> UIDS: 48-45
>
> ---
>
> Contract van 05/12/2014
>
> UIDS: 47

Can anyone be of assistance?

Comment: `$item['date'] === $lastitem['date']` will only be true with the 19th in your current data set. so only for the 19th would you start combining things.

Comment: Thanks Marc, but if I remove this, I get errors: Notice: Undefined index: start in /var/www/vhosts/yxz.be/subdomains/yxz/httpdocs/content/projects.php on line 816

Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object in /var/www/vhosts/yxz.be/subdomains/yxz/httpdocs/content/projects.php on line 816

Comment: If I change that rule to: 
`if ($lastdate != NULL && $date->diff($lastdate)->days <= 1) {`
The error is gone, but the ranges are still wrong. I get 17/09-18/09 and 19/09-20/09 and 05/12