# Selecting list of dates in MySQL - grouping those that are consecutive

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way for MySQL to return a list of dates and group those that are consecutive, or would I need to process the raw list of dates with PHP [as per this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8461543/check-for-consecutive-dates-within-a-set-and-return-as-range):

Example columns:

```
start            end
2015-01-01       2015-01-01
2015-01-03       2015-01-03
2015-01-04       2015-01-04
2015-01-05       2015-01-05
2015-01-10       2015-01-10
2015-01-11       2015-01-11
```

I am looking for the following result:

```
start            end
2015-01-01       2015-01-01
2015-01-03       2015-01-05
2015-01-10       2015-01-11
```

Thanks for the help SO!

Comment: Your going to have to use PHP to achieve what you're looking for.

Comment: ...or at least a SQL routine. Some kind of executable code, anyhow.

Comment: Rick James idea in his answer below comes very close.

Comment: @WhirlMind sorry which answer?

Comment: Oops, sorry Ryan, I thought I saw an answer by Rick James, that involved self-join, can't place it now. With looping it's quite possible. I have been trying for some solution without looping, haven't made any breakthrough. In the meanwhile, here's some link, for whatever cues it can give. 
http://www.codediesel.com/mysql/sequence-gaps-in-mysql/