# How can I shrink two dates in to one date range?

Tags: php, date, time, range

I need to display date ranges like the following:

- May 5-7, 2015
- April 29-May 5, 2015
- December 30 2015-January 1, 2016

I'm provided a start date and an end date as PHP date objects. Is there a way I can parse those with PHP to output as needed?

---

**EDIT: I think you guys are misunderstanding what I'm looking to do.**

I've got a WordPress events plugin that outputs a start date and an end date. If an event has a start date of May 4, 2015, and an end date of May 7, 2015, I need to display this:

```
<h4>Event Title</h4>
<p>When: <time>May 4-7, 2015</time></p>
```

I don't need to display each date between the given dates; that's easy enough for me to figure out on my own.

---

**EDIT 2:** Alright, just to make sure I'm being completely clear:

I'm using the Tri.be Events plugin to allow a user to create a calendar of events. On the front page for this WordPress site, I need to display a list of upcoming events. Each event should be output like this:

[image]

This event should be output like this:

```
<article>
    <h4><a href="/path/to/event/">Systematic Implementation of Advance Care Planning in a Diverse City</a></h4>
    <p>
        <a href="/path/to/event/">
            Aging in America Conference - Chicago, IL<br />
            <time datetime="2015-03-23">March 23-27, 2015</time>
        </a>
    </p>
</article>
```

The bit I'm having trouble with is the `<time>` element. The answers below seem to indicate that I want to output the time in this format:

```
<time datetime="2015-03-23">March 23, 2015 - March 27, 2015</time>
```

This is incorrect. If that where the case, I could easily output this on my own. The correct format is:

```
<time datetime="2015-03-23">March 23-27, 2015</time>
```

Thus, the question is: "How can I shrink two dates in to one date range?"

Comment: Have you checked http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php ?

Comment: https://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php

Comment: Yes, I've checked the manual and it doesn't provide what I need. Please see the updated question.

Comment: Specify your question even more. See my answer below.

Comment: See Edit 2, I don't think I could be any more clear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT 2:**

I have updated the function with some date format.

Output will be:

> **Event title**
>
> When: Feb 28, 2010 - Mar 2, 2010
>
> **Event title**
>
> When: Mar 4, 2010 - Mar 5, 2010
>
> **Event title**
>
> When: Dec 31, 2010 - Jan 5, 2011

**EDIT:**

I found this (by searching) -- > [Check for consecutive dates within a set and return as range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8461543/check-for-consecutive-dates-within-a-set-and-return-as-range)

The code below isn't mine. It's an old post from [@Darragh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/312962/darragh)

> I have made some minor changes to the code to fit the OP's question.

```
    // assuming a chronologically
    // ordered array of DateTime objects 

    $dates = array(         
          new DateTime('2010-02-28'), 
          new DateTime('2010-03-01'), 
          new DateTime('2010-03-02'), 
          new DateTime('2010-03-04'), 
          new DateTime('2010-03-05'), 
          new DateTime('2010-12-31'),
          new DateTime('2011-01-01'), 
          new DateTime('2011-01-02'), 
          new DateTime('2011-01-03'), 
          new DateTime('2011-01-04'), 
          new DateTime('2011-01-05'),
    );

    // process the array

    $lastDate = null;
    $ranges = array();
    $currentRange = array();

    foreach ($dates as $date) {    

        if (null === $lastDate) {
            $currentRange[] = $date;
        } else {

            // get the DateInterval object
            $interval = $date->diff($lastDate);

            // DateInterval has properties for 
            // days, weeks. months etc. You should 
            // implement some more robust conditions here to 
            // make sure all you're not getting false matches
            // for diffs like a month and a day, a year and 
            // a day and so on...

            if ($interval->days === 1) {
                // add this date to the current range
                $currentRange[] = $date;    
            } else {
                // store the old range and start anew
                $ranges[] = $currentRange;
                $currentRange = array($date);
            }
        }

        // end of iteration... 
        // this date is now the last date     
        $lastDate = $date;
    }

    // messy... 
    $ranges[] = $currentRange;

    // print dates

        foreach ($ranges as $range) {

    // there'll always be one array element, so 
    // shift that off and create a string from the date object 
    $startDate = array_shift($range);
    $str = "<h4>Event title</h4>";
    $str .= "<p>When: ";
    $str .= "<time>"; 
    $str .= sprintf('%s', $startDate->format('M j, Y'));
    // if there are still elements in $range
    // then this is a range. pop off the last 
    // element, do the same as above and concatenate
    if (count($range)) {
        $endDate = array_pop($range);
        $str .= sprintf(' - %s', $endDate->format('M j, Y'));
        $str .= "</time></p>";
    }

    echo "<p>$str</p>";
}
```

---

**Old answer** (based on original question).

```
$start_date = new DateTime( '2015-05-01' );
$end_date = new DateTime( '2015-05-04' );
$end_date = $end_date->modify( '+1 day' ); 

$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$daterange = new DatePeriod($start_date, $interval ,$end_date);

foreach($daterange as $date){
    echo $date->format("M d, Y") . "<br>";
}

// Output
// May 01, 2015
// May 02, 2015
// May 03, 2015
// May 04, 2015
```

Comment: Pretty sure you've misunderstood what I"m looking for as everyone else apparently has. I've updated the question to be more clear.

Comment: Why a downvote? I help you. You downvote. Be more clear of what you want.

Comment: Because it's answer a different question than what I asked. Please see the updated question.

Comment: But, why downvoting an answer based on the original question? The effort and the time surely must mean something? Crazy.

Comment: It doesn't answer the original question. You misunderstood the original question. I'll upvote if you can help me solve the actual question.

Comment: Please see my updates. I have made some adjustments due to your question. foreach ($ranges as $range) {
    
        $startDate = array_shift($range);
     $str = "<h4>Event title</h4>";
     $str .= "<p>When: ";
     $str .= "<time>";
        $str .= sprintf('%s', $startDate->format('M j'));
        
        if (count($range)) {
            $endDate = array_pop($range);
            $str .= sprintf(' - %s', $endDate->format('j, Y'));
      $str .= "</time></p>";
        }
    
        echo "<p>$str</p>";
    }

Comment: This looks close enough to work off of, especially that question you linked to. I'll mark as answer if I get it working. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
<article>
    <h4><a href="/path/to/event/">Systematic Implementation of Advance Care Planning in a Diverse City</a></h4>
    <p>
        <a href="/path/to/event/">
            Aging in America Conference - Chicago, IL<br />
            <time datetime="2015-03-23/2015-03-27">March 23&ndash;27 2015</time>
        </a>
    </p>
</article>
```

**Edit**

Complete example with PHP-code above.

> Output
>
> Mar 23, 2015–Mar 27, 2015

```
    // assuming a chronologically
    // ordered array of DateTime objects 

    $dates = array(         
          new DateTime('2015-03-23'), 
          new DateTime('2015-03-24'), 
          new DateTime('2015-03-25'), 
          new DateTime('2015-03-26'), 
          new DateTime('2015-03-27')          
    );

    // process the array

    $lastDate = null;
    $ranges = array();
    $currentRange = array();

    foreach ($dates as $date) {    

        if (null === $lastDate) {
            $currentRange[] = $date;
        } else {

            // get the DateInterval object
            $interval = $date->diff($lastDate);

            // DateInterval has properties for 
            // days, weeks. months etc. You should 
            // implement some more robust conditions here to 
            // make sure all you're not getting false matches
            // for diffs like a month and a day, a year and 
            // a day and so on...

            if ($interval->days === 1) {
                // add this date to the current range
                $currentRange[] = $date;    
            } else {
                // store the old range and start anew
                $ranges[] = $currentRange;
                $currentRange = array($date);
            }
        }

        // end of iteration... 
        // this date is now the last date     
        $lastDate = $date;
    }

    // messy... 
    $ranges[] = $currentRange;

    // print dates

    foreach ($ranges as $range) {

    // there'll always be one array element, so 
    // shift that off and create a string from the date object 
    $startDate = array_shift($range);
    $str = "<h4>Event title</h4>";
    $str .= "<p>When: ";
    $str .= "<time>"; 
    $str .= sprintf('%s', $startDate->format('M j, Y'));
    // if there are still elements in $range
    // then this is a range. pop off the last 
    // element, do the same as above and concatenate
    if (count($range)) {
        $endDate = array_pop($range);
        $str .= sprintf(' - %s', $endDate->format('M j, Y'));
        $str .= "</time></p>";
    }

}

echo "<time datetime=".$startDate->format('M j, Y')."/".$endDate->format('M j, Y').">".$startDate->format('M j, Y')."&ndash;".$endDate->format('M j, Y')."</time>";

//OUTPUT
// Mar 23, 2015–Mar 27, 2015
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be the simplest solution:

```
$dtStart = new DateTime('2015-05-05');
$dtEnd   = new DateTime('2015-05-07');

while ($dtStart <= $dtEnd) {
    echo $dtStart->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
    $dtStart->modify('+1 day');
}

// Output:
// 2015-05-05
// 2015-05-06
// 2015-05-07

$dtStart = new DateTime('2015-12-30');
$dtEnd   = new DateTime('2016-01-01');

while ($dtStart <= $dtEnd) {
    echo $dtStart->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
    $dtStart->modify('+1 day');
}

// Output:
// 2015-12-30
// 2015-12-31
// 2016-01-01
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I was going for; please see the updated question.