# Check if dates are continuous with PHP

Tags: php, date

How can I check in this string that the date are continuous ?

```
$dates = "2017-01-08, 2017-01-09, 2017-01-10";
```

For this example, the 3 dates are continuous.

```
$dates = "2017-01-08, 2017-01-12, 2017-01-13";
```

For this example, the 3 dates are not continuous.

Any help for this ?

Thanks.

Comment: How specific do you need to be? Would `2016-02-28, 2016-03-01` be valid?

Comment: @chris85: nice point. Yes it should be valid.

Comment: 2016 was a leap year so `2016-02-29` is missing there, that is fine though? You can probably tweak this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8461543/check-for-consecutive-dates-within-a-set-and-return-as-range.

Comment: @chris85: ho so it should be considered as invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `DateTime::diff` function, you can get the difference in days. Then loop over the dates, and if the difference isn't one day, it's not continuous.

```
$dates = "2017-01-08, 2017-01-09, 2017-01-10";
var_dump(check_continuous_dates($dates)); // true

$dates = "2017-01-08, 2017-01-12, 2017-01-13";
var_dump(check_continuous_dates($dates)); // false

function check_continuous_dates($date) {
    $date = explode(", ", $date); // Convert it to an array we can loop
    $previous = new DateTime($date[0]); // Set the "previous" value
    unset($date[0]); // Unset the value we just set to $previous, so we don't loop it twice

    foreach ($date as $v) { // Loop the array
        $current = new DateTime($v);
        $diff = $current->diff($previous);

        // If the difference is exactly 1 day, it's continuous 
        if ($diff->days == 1) {
            $previous =  new DateTime($v);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

[**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/2E3kt)

## References

- http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Answer (score 1):

```
$datesArr = preg_split('/,\s+/', $dates);
$startDate = new DateTime(array_shift($datesArr));
foreach($datesArr as $date) {
   if ($date !== $startDate->modify("+1 day")->format("Y-m-d")) {
     // not continuous
   }
}
```