# Create date ranges from single dates

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have a database that is filled with single dates, for example:

```
date
----------
2017-11-01
2017-11-02
2017-11-03
2017-11-04
2017-11-05
2017-11-06
2017-12-14
2017-12-15
2017-12-16
2017-12-17
2018-01-04
```

I need a way to output these values as date ranges using PHP. Using the example dates, my expected result should be like this:

```
2017-11-01 - 2017-11-06
2017-12-14 - 2017-12-17
2018-01-04 - 2018-01-04
```

Have anyone done this before, or know the best way to accomplish this?

Thank you!

Comment: Are dates always concecutive ? could this happen: 11-01, 11-02, 11-05, 11-06 ? this would change the reply, thats why i ask :)

Comment: Yes. Dates are always consecutive. If a date is missing, it should create a new date range for the following dates. Thank you! :)

Comment: @MagnusAlexander *"If a date is missing"* - That could make a big difference here. See Gordon's answer. If that doesn't work, then you will need to let him know what you want to do here exactly.

Comment: @MagnusAlexander last question, what about 11-30, 12-01, 12-02. is this 2 ranges or the same range ? comes down to: does the month change create a new group ?

Comment: I understand :) If the dates are 11-05, 11-06, 11-07, 11-09, 11-10, 11-11, the ranges would be 11-05 - 11-07 and 11-09 - 11-11.

Comment: No, 11-30, 12-01, 12-02 is one range as the dates are consecutive.

Comment: @MagnusAlexander You stated: [*"However, I'm using a MS-SQL-based database on this project"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47158261/create-date-ranges-from-single-dates#comment81266279_47158331) under Gordon's answer. I retagged your post. This could have a huge bearing on (other) answers given. Please be as precise as possible when posting, it's important.

Comment: for a MySQL response, this is not bad for you: (but only php, no sql involved) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8461543/check-for-consecutive-dates-within-a-set-and-return-as-range

Comment: Thank you! I used Gordons code, and everything is ok. Thank you for your effort!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MS-SQL, this is much simpler.  Just use the difference with a row number:

```
select min(date), max(date)
from (select date, row_number() over (order by date) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by dateadd(day, - seqnum, date);
```

For MySQL (as the question was originally tagged), the simplest method is to use variables:

```
select min(date), max(date)
from (select t.*,
             (@grp := if(date = @d + interval 1 day,
                         if(@date := @d, @grp, @grp),
                         if(@date := @d, @grp + 1, @grp + 1)
                        )
             ) grp
      from (select date
            from t
            order by date
           ) t cross join
           (select @grp := 0, @d) params
     ) t
group by grp;
```

Comment: Thank you! I can see that this would work well on a MySQL database. However, I'm using a MS-SQL-based database on this project, and I don't know how to rewrite the code for this purpose. But thank you very much for the answer! :)

Comment: @MagnusAlexander . . . You should tag your questions correctly.

Comment: I know, and I am sorry. I changed it as soon as I saw it. Honest mistake!

Comment: @MagnusAlexander *"I changed it as soon as I saw it."* - No you didn't, [you removed the mysql tag and added the sql tag](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/47158261/2). --- [I added the sql-server tag](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/47158261/3). "sql" != "mssql/sql-server".

Answer (score 1):

To do the same thing in MS-SQl try:

```
    WITH    dateTable
          AS (SELECT    CAST('2017-11-01' AS DATE) date
              UNION ALL
              SELECT    DATEADD(DAY, 3, date)
              FROM      dateTable
              WHERE     date < '2018-04-01'
             )
    SELECT  MIN(date)
    ,       MAX(date)
    FROM    dateTable
    GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, date)
    ,       DATEPART(MONTH, date)
```

Assuming you want first and last date for each month in the year. The common table expression here is just for getting some test data and can be ignored when you select from your own data. Iterative cte's should usually be avoided for efficiency reasons.

Answer (score 1):

By using Window functions also we can achieve it with partition by month wise min and max.

```
;WITH Cte([Date])
    AS
    (
    SELECT '2017-11-01' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2017-11-02' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2017-11-03' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2017-11-04' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2017-11-05' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2017-11-06' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2017-12-14' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2017-12-15' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2017-12-16' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2017-12-17' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2018-01-04' 

    )
    SELECT DISTINCT MIN([Date]) OVER(PARTITION BY DATEPART(MM,[Date]) ORDER BY (SELECT(NULL))) AS StartDate,
                    MAX([Date]) OVER(PARTITION BY DATEPART(MM,[Date]) ORDER BY (SELECT(NULL))) AS EndDate FROM Cte
```