# multiple date array concatenate to string

Tags: php, function, date

I'd like to create a string out of multiple date.

```
$dates_group1 = array('2015-10-30', '2015-10-31', '2015-11-01');
$dates_group2 = array('2015-10-31', '2015-10-01', '2015-11-02');
$dates_group3 = array('2015-10-29', '2015-10-31', '2015-11-01');

Oct 30-31, Nov 01
Oct 31, Nov 1-2
Oct 29,31, Nov 1
```

Is there any php function to do that? It seems like it happen pretty often.

Comment: There is not: `build_my_yellow_purple_special_house()`, but there are functions like: `hammer()`, `wrench()`, `screwdriver()`.

Comment: start with `implode`

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33874059/3933332 To get some ideas.

Comment: So where are we with this question? Did the linked question helped you?